# Time validation with java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to archive something like that I would like that my  Input is Interpreted as

- 2 =  2 hours
- 15 = 15 mins
- .5 = 30 mins
- 2:45 = 2 hrs, 45 min

So what I did is more or less something like this is just checking for ":" and hours 24 but i seams such a endless function ..

```
    function validateTime(obj)
{
    var timeValue = obj.value;
    if(timeValue == "" || timeValue.indexOf(":")<0)
    {
        alert("Invalid Time format");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var sHours = timeValue.split(':')[0];
        var sMinutes = timeValue.split(':')[1];

        if(sHours == "" || isNaN(sHours) || parseInt(sHours)>23)
        {
            alert("Invalid Time format");
            return false;
        }
        else if(parseInt(sHours) == 0)
            sHours = "00";
        else if (sHours <10)
            sHours = "0"+sHours;

        if(sMinutes == "" || isNaN(sMinutes) || parseInt(sMinutes)>59)
        {
            alert("Invalid Time format");
            return false;
        }
        else if(parseInt(sMinutes) == 0)
            sMinutes = "00";
        else if (sMinutes <10)
            sMinutes = "0"+sMinutes;    

        obj.value = sHours + ":" + sMinutes;        
    }

    return true;    
    }
```

Comment: what is your question??

Comment: so, 2 is 2 hours, 15 is 15 minutes ... what would 10 be? 10 hours or 10 minutes

Comment: [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: So anything less than 12 is hours? Above 12 minutes?

Comment: @JaromandaX 1-9 is hours everything above 9 is minutes